# Alternating row colours in CSS with nested levels

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for the best way to implement alternating row colours for a theoretically infinite number of nested levels. Below is an example of the markup i'm testing with and the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DFn82/

With nth-child it's very difficult to get the alternating colours to work correctly, you need to effectively hardcode the combinations for each level and the css rules grow exponentially.

I can achieve the result I want using javascript, however the lists are completely dynamic and things are added and removed constantly. Performance wise using javascript doesn't seem like an option and could have some pretty massive implications.

This only needs to work in IE9+

[image]

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Item</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Item</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Item</span>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <span>Item</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Item</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Item</span>
                <ul>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                    <li><span>Item</span></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Paul. Will you please rephrase with an actual question? I think you are asking "Is there a better way to do this with CSS?"

Comment: Also, are you wanting a CSS solution that works to an arbitrary number of levels, without having to provide the specific cases in CSS?

Comment: you should write a function in javascript and should cal it whenever you need. It won't affect performance, since you are having very few items. If you need i can try that function.

Comment: Is your example how you want it, or how it's wrong? Do you want the 5th row in your example to be green?

Comment: @RoToRa I think the example shows how it works at the first nesting, but does not work at the second nesting.

Comment: You can easily avoid javascript. Write a little script to generate the CSS for the appropriate number of nesting levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such implementation is not possible via css only. You will have to use javascript. Also, usage of JS shouldn't cause such horrible performance. Just have JS check and update whenever new values are added or removed. Then, we're talking about a performance of linearly dependent on number of rows. Hardly different from the browser trying to figure it out from css rules if it were possible (also linearly dependent on number of rows or worse).

Comment: Yes, this is impossible with CSS because it doesn't have a notion of nth nesting depth.

Comment: I thought this was the case, however wanted to fire out the question incase someone new of a new pseudo selector that may make this possible.

I'm using websockets to pull back data, stuff is coming back incredibly quickly and in chunks. As each chunks comes back it is written to the DOM. Overall there could be ~ 3,000 rows, they may be nested and each level is collapsable.

Just didn't want to keep recalculating in JS every time I run a redraw or expand/collapse a section of the hierarchy. But I guess the browser is running similar calculations in order to render the styles.